# Show views above lockscreen using window manager in Android O?

Tags: android, android-view, android-windowmanager, android-8.0-oreo

My app shows views above the lockscreen, until now I used the following code:

```
windowParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT, 65794, -2);
windowParams.type = Utils.isSamsung(getApplicationContext()) ? WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST : WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR;
windowManager.addView(frameLayout, windowParams);
```

This code doesn't seem to work anymore on Android O, instead, now the lockscreen is shown above the view, and the view only becomes visible after the user swipes away the lockscreen.
Granted, it could just be a bug since Android O is still in beta, but it's also possible that I missed one of Googles notes about "what's new in O".

Comment: https://developer.android.com/preview/behavior-changes.html#all-aw https://developer.android.com/preview/behavior-changes.html#cwt

Comment: Thanks! that must be it

Comment: Well, even after using the new layout params type, I still can't show views above the lockscreen

Comment: The docs have: "An app's alert windows always appear under critical system windows, such as the status bar and IMEs". Personally, I would consider the lockscreen to be critical system window. Beyond that, create a reproducible test case and [file an issue against the developer preview](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid%3A190602%20status%3Aopen).

Comment: Thanks, that seems like a very short sighted solution for a complex issue.
Seems like there's already an open issue for this:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62081223

Comment: To flip it around, I had no idea that you could float a window over the lockscreen. That would seem to open the door for local DoS by preventing the user from entering their PIN or otherwise getting past that lockscreen. In much of Android 4.x, we had support for app widgets on the lockscreen, and I thought that was a reasonable middle ground. I'm not sure why they dumped those.

Comment: You already had to grant apps with special permission to draw over other apps, I would find it reasonable to let user grant another special permissions for apps that require this feature.
I found another open issue related to this:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36574245
Seems like the development team decided to not fix it.
This is very frustrating as one of my apps rely on this feature as well as many other apps in the Google Play Store.
I really don't understand Google's decision to outright kill hundreds of apps

Comment: If there's a silver lining to this, is that it takes Google at least 2 years to streamline updates, so I'll get to watch my app die slowly and rather than instantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's no longer possible to draw over the lockscreen and other important UI elements (status bar, etc), Google removed this feature in Android O.

Source:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36574245

Comment: any idea how truecaller is doing that?